# Quaternion Algebras and zero divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field, noncommutative-algebra

I am going through a paper, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0196677488900144 and over there I found this statement in pg 2 confusing-

The structure of associative algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$ is of the form $M_n(F)$, where $F$ is a field containing $\mathbb{Q}$.

I looked up wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_algebra and there I found,

Every quaternion algebra becomes a matrix algebra by extending scalars (equivalently, tensoring with a field extension), i.e. for a suitable field extension $K$ of $F$, ${\displaystyle A\otimes _{F}K}$ is isomorphic to the 2×2 matrix algebra over K. But it did not become clear.

Another point which stuck from the paper and also in wikipedia it is written the same.

A quaternion algebra $(a,b)_F$ is either a division algebra or isomorphic to the matrix algebra of $2×2$ matrices over $F$.

The above statement follows from Wedderburn Artin structure theorem according to the paper. But on looking into that, the thing did not become clear.

Can anyone help me out understanding those two points I mentioned, or maybe suggest some materials to read?

Comment: Perhaps an example will make things clear. Start with the ordinary (Hamilton) quaternions, $\Bbb H$. The coefficients here of the $1$, the $i$, the $j$, and the $k$ are always real numbers. Can you show that when you allow complex coefficients instead, you get something isomorphic to the ring of two-by-two complex matrices?

Comment: Why are you emphasizing on complex? Does it play a role here?

Comment: The complex numbers are the only finite extension of $\Bbb R$, which is the constant field of $\Bbb H$. If you have a different quaternion algebra over, say, the field $\Bbb Q$, then you could get the same matrix behavior with other extensions. Indeed, the standard formulas give you a quaternion algebra over $\Bbb Q$, and it “splits”, i.e. becomes a matrix algebra over both $\Bbb Q(i)$ and $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-2})$.

Comment: $2\times2$ matrices are split-quaternions, which is entirely different thing.